# How to upload a small JSON object in memory to Google BigQuery in Python?

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

Is there any way to take a small data JSON object from memory and upload it to Google BigQuery without using the file system?

We have working code that uploads files to BigQuery. This code no longer works for us because our new script runs on Google App Engine which doesn't have write access to the file system.

We notice that our BigQuery upload configuration has a "MediaFileUpload" option with a data_path. We have been unable to find if there is some way to change the data_path to something in memory - or if there is another method apart from MediaFileUpload that could upload data from memory to BigQuery.

```
 media_body=MediaFileUpload(
            data_path,
            mimetype='application/octet-stream'))
 job = insert_request.execute()
```

We have seen solutions which recommend uploading data to Google Cloud Storage then referencing that file to upload to BigQuery for when datasets are large. Our dataset is small so this step seems like an unnecessary use of bandwidth, processing and time.

As a result, we are wondering if there is a way to take our small JSON object and upload it directly to BigQuery using Python?

Comment: Could you make a POST request to the API endpoint (e.g. [tabledata.insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll)) with the JSON payload?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard This does look promising. We will give it a try.

Comment: If you come up with something that works, consider adding it as an answer to help future people with the same question. Thanks!